# How to create socket dynamically on lighttpd server?

Tags: webserver, centos, lighttpd

We are hosting more than 200 websites/users on the lighttpd web server. When we keep all the socket connection open/active, the memory consumption is very high.
We want to create the socket, on demand when there is a request. How can we do it ?

I am trying to connect test user through this socket ( /etc/my-project/fastcgi/test.socket ), If this socket is killed or not existing, then we get 503 error.

Lighttpd user config file,

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "8484" {
$HTTP["cookie"] =~ "test" {
fastcgi.server = (
".php" => (
"localhost" => (
"socket" => "/etc/my-project/fastcgi/test.socket",
"max-procs" => 2,
"bin-copy-environment" => (
"PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
```

This is example config file.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for `"min-procs"`
`"min-procs" => 0` is an option.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI#Options